# Inserted Button inside DOM to content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox-addon

I'm writing a firefox extension and have the following problem:

I added inside a content script (insertInDom.js) a Button

```
$('#leftCol').append("<input type='button' value='Check Privacy' onclick=\"buttonClick()\" >");
```

After the user clicked the button a function from the content script should be started, but I always get the *error Fehler: buttonClick is not defined*

how can I react on the event of an inserted Button inside my script? Thank you :)

The whole relevant code:

main.js

```
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: ["http://www.facebook.com/"],
    contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
    contentScriptFile: [data.url('jquery-1.6.4.js'),
                       data.url('insertInDom.js')],
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        worker.port.on('buttonClicked', function(content) {
            console.log(content);
        });
    }
});
```

insertInDom.js:

```
function buttonClick(){
    self.port.emit("buttonClicked", "true");
}

$('#leftCol').append("<input type='button' value='Check Privacy' onclick=\"buttonClick()\" >");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.7, I think the appropriate way to add a click event (even to a DOM element that has been created after the initial page is loaded is like so:

```
$("#dataTable tbody tr").on("click", function(event){
alert($(this).text());
});
```

docs: http://api.jquery.com/on/

So, you could try adding an ID to your input and then something like:

```
   $("#myInput").on("click", function(event){
      self.port.emit("buttonClicked", "true");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using jQuery, why not make use of jQuery to handle your click event? Also, I try to make a habit of using jQuery to build DOM elements - it will make sure you don't stumble upon some unlikely browser issues.

```
$('<input />', { type: 'button', value: 'Check Privacy' })
    .on('click', buttonClick)
    .appendTo('#leftCol');
```